# How to webpage to image with drag & drop?

Tags: php, jquery, html

my current employer wanted me to make a page that allows users to drag and drop images and texts onto the background then it would be saved as a jpg or png file to the server. The drag and drop is enabled by jQuery and the backend is php. I have tried html2canvas but it always gives me a "Canvas is tainted, unable to read data" error. Is there any way to do this?

```
            $(function() {
            $( "#1" ).draggable({ snap: true });
            $( "#2" ).draggable({ snap: ".screen" });
            $( "#3" ).draggable({ snap: ".screen" });
            $( "#4" ).draggable({ snap: ".ui-widget-header", snapMode: "outer" });
            $( "#5" ).draggable({ grid: [ 20,20 ] });
            $( "#6" ).draggable({ grid: [ 80, 80 ] });
            $("#7").change(function() {
                //alert($(this).val());
                $('.changeMe').css("font-family", $(this).val());
            });

            $("#8").change(function() {
                //alert($(this).val());
                $('.changeMe').css("color", $(this).val());
            });

            $("#9").change(function() {
                $('.changeMe').css("font-size", $(this).val() + "px");
            });
```

Comment: Fancy sharing some code?

Comment: just added the jquery code